# Gaussian Maximum Likelihood estimator vs. Maximum Likelihood estimator

Tags: normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, terminology

What is the difference between the Gaussian Maximum Likelihood estimator and the Maximum Likelihood estimator?

I found the term Gaussian MLE in several papers. For instance:

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/948646

https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03610929308831013

https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1467-9892.2006.00492.x

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X12000851

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1163688

Comment: Can you give more details about your problem? For example, where did you see the term *Gaussian MLE*?

Comment: I added some references where the term Gaussian MLE is used.

Comment: Seems like the likelihood function is Gaussian, and the method is being used for stationary Gaussian assumed processes.  http://eprints.lse.ac.uk/5825/1/Gaussian_maximum_likelihood_estimation_for_ARMA_models_I(LSERO).pdf